# How to get the browser to display when running a live server test case with Selenium under django

Tags: python, django, selenium

I have tests that use the django LiveServerTestCase, pyvirtualdisplay, and Selenium. Normally they run from cron and I don't have a display, so I do this:

```
cls.display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
cls.display.start()
```

Which works fine. But when debugging a new test I would like to run from the command line and have the browser be displayed. I've tried many different things, e.g. setting visible to 1. That failed with:

WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Error: cannot open display: :1207\n'

I tried commenting out those lines and got:

WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Error: no display specified\n'

I tired running the test with xvfb-run:

xvfb-run python manage.py test cdsem.W2WTestLive

Like this the test ran, but the browser did not display. I tried this:

DISPLAY=:1 xvfb-run python manage.py test cdsem.W2WTestLive

and still the browser did not display. I did google this and search SO, and it seems to be a very common question, but none of the answers worked for me. How can I run this test from the command line and have the browser be visible?

Comment: When you start the process, is it running in the background or the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

Just stop using the virtual display?  By default selenium will open up a visible browser on your active display... So you can just hack in, say:

```
if False:
    cls.display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    cls.display.start()
```

while you are testing locally... You could use environment variables or something for a more permanent solution...